# Grep -v "Ready" without taking out "Not Ready"

Tags: bash

```
oc get serviceinstances | grep -v Ready
```

There are some results that are "Not Ready" but it would take them out as well because it looks for "Ready".

There are lots of different status names and "Ready" are the only ones I don't need.

For instance:

1. Ready
2. Not Ready
3. Error
4. Failed

I need "Not Ready", "Error", "Failed"

Comment: Could you show a sample input ?

Comment: Added an sample input

Comment: `grep -i 'ready' test | grep -v 'not ready'`

Comment: @Ostone0 `grep -i 'ready' test | grep -vi 'not ready'`, maybe?

Comment: The suggested duplicate question is not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: @Tom S Please show the output of `oc get serviceinstances`. Please do this in your question, not in comments, external links, images...

Comment: Added an image, I hope it will be clearer

Comment: I think you're asking *not* to see Ready, so use `grep -E "Not Ready|Error|Failed"`

Comment: There are about 10+ different statues, so what I was asking is not to see "Ready" but anything else, including "Not Ready"

Comment: @TomS Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead. And do not forget to indicate what is the field separator in the output of `oc get serviceinstances`. Tabs? Spaces?

Answer (score 0):

When the fields are separated by tabs, use

```
oc get serviceinstances | grep -E "\tReady\t"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
... | gawk '/\s+Not Ready\s+/ || !/\s+Ready\s+/'
```

Answer (score 0):

oc get serviceinstances | egrep "Not Ready|Error|Failed"

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports `-P` (PCRE support) option, please try:

```
oc get serviceinstances | grep -v -P "(?<!Not )Ready"
```

The regex matches `Ready` unless it is preceded by `Not` , then the logic is negated by the `-v` option.